# Pass function processing data of specific type to another function that accepts a function processing a union of types

Tags: typescript

With the code below:

```
interface DataOne {
    strings: string[],
}

interface DataTwo {
    numbers: number[],
}

const Component = (onDataReceived: (data: DataOne | DataTwo) => void) => {
    const data: DataOne | DataTwo = {numbers: [1, 2, 3]}
    onDataReceived(data)
}

const onDataOneReceived = (data: DataOne) => console.log(data)
Component(onDataOneReceived)
```

I get the following compile error:

> Argument of type '(data: DataOne) => void' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(data: DataOne | DataTwo) => void'.   Types of
> parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
> Type 'DataOne | DataTwo' is not assignable to type 'DataOne'.
> Property 'strings' is missing in type 'DataTwo' but required in type 'DataOne'.

I tried solving it by introducing type guards (narrowing) and generic types for both `Component` and `onDataReceived`, but to no avail.
Could someone guide how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of contravariance.
See this example:

```js
interface DataOne {
  strings: string[],
}

interface DataTwo {
  numbers: number[],
}

declare let a: DataOne | DataTwo
declare let b: DataOne

a = b // ok

let fnA = (data: DataOne | DataTwo) => {
  data
}
let fnB = (data: DataOne) => { }

fnA = fnB // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NDyRzm)

In first example, `b` is assignable to `a`, however in second example is not. Function arguments are in contravariant position. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) question/answer for more explanation about *-variance.